# Obscuring Default Plaintext password in Powershell (PowerCLI) script

Tags: passwords, powercli

I am working on a PowerCLI script that deploy and configure VMs from a template. During the configuration phase I have to run some commands which require the Guest's root Username and Password to run Scripts on the VM. These are the Template's default credentials and they are stored as plaintext in my script. After configuration is complete I have the User change their passwords using SecureString Credentials.

What has me worried is that due to the nature of the VM's I am configuring there is a large window of opportunity for someone to access this VM if they can find the default plain-text credentials I have in my script. Is there a way of storing the default credentials in the script that is encrypted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to store credentials encrypted against the users account using trusted storage and `ConvertTo-SecureString`.

Here's how to encrypt a value against your account, where the value you want to encrypt is stored in `$Password`.  Make sure to set the a path to store the password in a file too, under `$configDir`.

```
$Password = "SomeValue"
#Path to store the credential
$configDir = "$Env:AppData\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\YourScriptName\0.1\Config.ps1xml"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "SomeValue" -AsPlainText -Force
$password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Export-Clixml $configDir -Force
```

Now, to recover the password from encryption:

```
$password = Import-Clixml -Path $configDir -ErrorAction STOP | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Ptr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode($password)
$password= [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($Ptr)
```

And you'll end up with your password stored with `$password`.

Comment: This script will have to be run on each users account correct? I will be giving these scripts (and this VM template) to various clients whose knowledge of Powershell vary widely. To accommodate the lowest common denominator I'd have to give them your code as a script. However the problem is that the default password will still be in it as Plaintext. I guess I'd probably have to instruct the clients to delete the password initialization script after it's used or delete it my self.

Comment: The output of the first bit is a ps1xml file which can be converted back to a plaintext password, using the code from the second bit. This can only be used on the same computer where encrypted, though.

Comment: To be specific, if you're using these scripts from a certain pc, to send instructions to a VM, you should be safe to use this approach. Only someone logged on to that pc as you could decrypt the file, and get the default values for VMs